# Identifying SMT element 331K

Tags: capacitor, identification, surface-mount, repair, remote-control

[image: teh element]
I am trying to repair a remote from a car lock. The symptoms are that a red led is lit longer than usual after button press and no respond from car lock. It works sometimes. The battery and microswitches are replaced. All elements are resoldered. On the other side of the board is a tantalum capacitor. I measured it and is ok. (1uF 106)

### What is this element on the right? It has 1Ω resistance

EDIT:
I desoldered the similar looking element which on the picture is still soldered. It says 560J and is totally short: 0Ω.

On the other side of the board is a capacitor similar looking but with a bar on the positive pole. The capacitor has 106 marking and is working.

Comment: Is it a shorted capacitor?

Comment: If you reverse the probes when you measure the resistance, do you still get 1Ω ?

Comment: Yes. And my cables are .1Ω So really it should be .9Ω

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this were a capacitor, I'd say by the shape and size that it have to be tantalum. However, tantalum caps are polarized, and this device is not. Ergo, not likely a cap.

The triangular marking at the top of the device resembles the Epcos logo:

[image]

A quick check of Epcos shows me that they have a line of [SM inductors](http://www.epcos.com/web/generator/Web/Sections/ProductCatalog/Inductors/Inductors/SMTInductors/Page,locale=en.html) which closely resemble your part, in both shape and markings.

[image]

This data sheet says that the line 331K represents the inductance and the bottom line is a date code.

[This note](http://www.epcos.com/web/generator/Web/Sections/ProductCatalog/Inductors/Inductors/SMTInductors/PDF/PDF__General,property=Data__en.pdf;/PDF_General.pdf) explains the code in more detail: K is a tolerance code (+/- 10%), and depending on the size of the part, the inductance is in either microhenries or nanohenries. I don't think your part is actually 330 microhenries given its size.

I think you have a 330nH EPCOS SM inductor. QED

Answer (score 3):

It is a coil for sure. I opened one.

[image: Coil]

[image: Coil]

Answer (score 2):

Hypothesis: these are SMT inductors.

It fits the observations.  Inductor has a low DC resistance.  Inductor doesn't require a polarization bar on the package.

Inductors like that do exist: [SP1008R-**331K**](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/API-Delevan/SP1008R-331K/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsg%252by3WlYCkU%252b7prI9pAzbeqLDAELI3/MU=), [1008-**560J**](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/API-Delevan/1008-560J/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsg%252by3WlYCkU/uy0w9T3GDQZq40TrZgKlo=)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Nick. Your answer is perfectly valid, but @Madmanguruman got more votes, so I accepted his answer. I really appreciate your engagement in this thread.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar device marked as : 331K and 9421 below, it is located in the power surge stage, before the protection diodes, so is almost sure that this device is a coil, it measures approx 2 Ohms. I found similar devices in another part of the circuit with the same value.

Answer (score 1):

You’re probably right that it’s a capacitor. 331K would stand for 330pf.

Edit: Upon further discussion, I’ve changed my opinion. @Passerby makes a good point that the elements are kind of large, and the fact that **both** of them have low resistance also argues against capacitors, as @Nick Alexeev points out (One of them could probably be a shortened capacitor, but both of them is less plausible).

Comment: How confident are you that this really is a shortened capacitor?

Comment: @martini  "How confident", eh?  "How confident" are you that this is _not_ a capacitor?  If you have doubts, provide the detailed doubts.

Comment: I’m not the world’s foremost expert on capacitors, but the labeling and form factor certainly make it plausible, cf [this capacitor](http://www.okokchina.com/p/Capacitors/CLX2-12289;CL22-12289;CL23-Metallized-Polyester-Film-Box-Capacitor-422495.html)

Comment: @NickAlexeev The capacitors usually have the polarity marking (a red bar) on one of their side. I just want a clear answer from someone who saw such a capacitor without a bar saying: Yes, Martin or NO! this is a inductor!

Comment: I wouldn’t expect such a small capacitor to be polarized, so the absence of a polarity marking would hardly be surprising.

Comment: @microtherion I wouldn't expect a 330pf capacitor to be that big either.

Comment: Yeah, good point.